# Олимпиадная задача. Выборы

Tags: java, алгоритм

> На выборах в Государственную думу в избирательные бюллетени внесено N
>   партий. Электронный сканер для считывания информации с бюллетеней
>   передает информацию о каждом бюллетене в следующем формате: если в
>   соответствующей клетке бюллетеня стоит пометка, то сканер передает +
>   (плюс), в противном случае он передает - (минус). Таким образом, он
>   передает последовательность из N символов - плюсов и минусов.
>
> Бюллетень считается действительным, если пометка есть ровно в одной
>   клетке. Недействительные бюллетени в подсчете результатов выборов не
>   участвуют.
>
> Партия проходит в Государственную Думу, только если она набирает не
>   менее 7% от общего числа действительных бюллетеней.
>
> Требуется вывести номера (в порядке их перечисления в бюллетене) всех
>   партий, которые проходят в Государственную Думу.
>
> **Входные данные** В первой строке входных данных содержатся два числа, разделенные пробелом: N - количество партий и M - количество
>   бюллетеней. Оба числа натуральные, N <= 200, M <= 100 000.
>
> В следующих M строках записана информация, полученная из бюллетеней.
>   Каждая строка - последовательность из N символов + или - (без
>   пробелов).
>
> Гарантируется, что есть хотя бы один действительный бюллетень.
>
> **Выходные данные** Выведите через пробел номера партий, прошедших в Думу, в порядке возрастания. Если ни одна из партий не проходит в
>   Думу,  выводить ничего не нужно.

Мое решение выглядит так:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class main1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str1 = reader.readLine();
        StringTokenizer stk1 = new StringTokenizer(str1," ");
        String []ar1 = new String[stk1.countTokens()];
        for(int i = 0; i<ar1.length; i++)
        {
            ar1[i] = stk1.nextToken();
        }
        //Выше - разбиение строки на массив
        int N = Integer.parseInt(ar1[0]); //Количество партий
        int M = Integer.parseInt(ar1[1]); //Количество бюллетеней
        int K = 0; //Количество действительных бюллетеней
        int[] result = new int[N]; //Количество голосов к партиям (0-я ячейка - первая партия, 1-я ячейка - вторая и т.д.)
        String[] P = new String[M]; //Бюллетени
        for (int a = 0; a < M; a++){
            P[a] = reader.readLine();
        }

        //Тут очистятся ячейки с недействительными бюллетенями, подсчитается количество действительных и распределятся голоса по партиям(result)
        for (int a = 0; a < P.length; a++){
            int i = 0;
            String parts[] = P[a].split("");
            for (int b = 0; b < parts.length; b++){
                if (parts[b].equals("+")) i++;
            }
            if (i != 1){
                continue;
            }else{
                K++;
                String parts1[] = P[a].split("");
                for (int b = 0; b < result.length; b++){
                    if (parts1[b].equals("+")) result[b] = result[b]+1;
                }
            }
        }

        //Проверяется условие (не меньше 7% от общего числа действительных бюллетеней) и выводится на экран через пробел
        for (int a = 0; a < result.length; a++){
            if (result[a] != 0){
                if ((result[a]*100)/K > 6) System.out.print(a+1+" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Не прошу решить задачу. Укажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка. Мой вариант проходит только 1 тест из 23. Какие данные использует тестирующая система при проверке решения - неизвестно.

Comment: вы предлагаете угадать какие трудности возникли?

Comment: Почему угадать? Условие есть, код тоже. Что же нужно еще?

Comment: и что же не так с вашим кодом?

Comment: Именно это я и хочу выяснить - что не так с моим кодом. При проверке кода все вроде бы получается, как и должно получаться. Но при сдаче проходит только 1 тест из 22.

Comment: получаете ли вы причину провала?

Comment: нет, ничего подобного не указывается

Comment: Может быть стоило упомянуть что за тесты вы проходите и что входит в те 22 теста, которые надо пройти?

Comment: Конечно, я бы упомянул. Но дело в том, что информация о тестах скрыта. Принцип работы: тесты используют какую-то входную информацию и сверяют ее с какой-то выходной. Скрыта информация для сложности, я так понимаю.

Comment: Под "скрытой информацией" я подразумеваю входные и выходные данные, которые используют тесты.

Comment: @Devlin эта задача имеет решение с линейной сложностью, без необходимости запоминать все данные. Видимо в этом и проблема.

Comment: @rdorn не могу точно утверждать, но я предполагаю, что тестирующая система проверяет только итоговый результат и на код, можно сказать, не смотрит

Comment: @ZZooRM на код совершенно точно не смотрит, но смотрит на потребление памяти и время выполнения, а это напрямую зависит от кода

Comment: @rdorn похоже на то. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тесты для олимпиадных задач учитывают время выполнения и количество используемой памяти, поэтому даже правильное решение может не пройти все тесты если не является оптимальным.

В вашем решении вы храните все исходные данные, хотя задача имеет решение не требующее такого объема памяти. Из всего набора исходных данных достаточно хранить только информацию о количестве бюллетеней и партий, а также текущем введенном бюллетене.

**Upd:**

Для начала исправим очевидное, не влияющее на ход решения.

Ваш вариант анализа строки описания бюллетеня использует памяти в трое больше чем необходимо (на самом деле еще немного больше, но это уже мелочи). Исправить это можно отказавшись от использования `split("")` который возвращает массив одно-символьных строк и вспомнить, что строка сама по себе массив и к ее элементам можно обращаться по индексу. Пример исправленного фрагмента (все переменные из исходного фрагмента ТС, оригинальные строки, требующие исправления, закоментированы):

```
int i = 0;
//String parts[] = P[a].split("");
//for (int b = 0; b < parts.length; b++)
for (int b = 0; b < P[a].length; b++)
{
    //if (parts[b].equals("+")) i++;
    if (P[a][b]=='+') i++;
}
if (i != 1)
{
    continue;//Переходим к обработке следующей строки
}
else
{
    K++;
    //String parts1[] = P[a].split("");
    for (int b = 0; b < result.length; b++)
    {
        //if (parts1[b].equals("+")) result[b] = result[b]+1;
        if (P[a][b]=='+') result[b] = result[b]+1;
    }
}
```

В принципе, одного этого изменения будет достаточно для уменьшения суммарной используемой памяти в 3 раза, что поможет пройти несколько больше тестов, но не все.

Следующим шагом необходимо избавиться от записи всех бюллетеней в массив строк и обрабатывать их по мере поступления. Заложенная в, предложенном ТС, коде идея алгоритма, позволяет внести соответствующие изменения достаточно безболезненно.